# beautifulsoup add <div> with class at end of html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file with multiple  tags (there are multiple div inside the div as well). I want to add a new  tag along with class to the end of the HTML at a specific position. I tried with *append*, *insert*, and *insert_after/insert_before* as well, however, it's not working as I expected.

My html input is:

```
   <div id="page">
   <div id="records">
   <div class="record">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>Here i want to print content</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="record">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display again once
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>Here i want to print content again once</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="record">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display second time
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>Here i want to print content second time</p>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to add new `<div>` tag with `class="record"` at the end, before the closing tag of **`<div id="records">`**.

output would look like this:

```
   <div id="page">
   <div id="records">
   <div class="record">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>Here i want to print content</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="record">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display again once
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>Here i want to print content again once</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="record">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display second time
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>Here i want to print content second time</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="record">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display 3rd time
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>Here i want to print content 3rd time</p>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In my case, the number of **`<div class="record">`** is not fixed, the number may vary always.

I would like to get a solution/suggestion for this problem using BeautifulSoup in python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert_after` after the last item in `soup.find_all('div', class_='record')`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div id="records"> <div class="record"> <div class="header"> <div class="title"> Something here to display </div> </div> <div class="disclaimer"> <p>Here i want to print content</p> </div> </div> <div class="record"> <div class="header"> <div class="title"> Something here to display again once </div> </div> <div class="disclaimer"> <p>Here i want to print content again once</p> </div> </div> <div class="record"> <div class="header"> <div class="title"> Something here to display second time </div> </div> <div class="disclaimer"> <p>Here i want to print content second time</p> </div> </div> </div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

extra_html = '''
<div class="record">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            Something here to display 3rd time
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="disclaimer">
        <p>Here i want to print content 3rd time</p>
    </div>
</div>'''

soup.find_all('div', class_='record')[-1].insert_after(BeautifulSoup(extra_html, 'html.parser')) # [-1] selects the last item
```

Output `print(soup.prettify())`:

```
<div id="records">
 <div class="record">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>
    Here i want to print content
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="record">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display again once
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>
    Here i want to print content again once
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="record">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display second time
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>
    Here i want to print content second time
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="record">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
    Something here to display 3rd time
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="disclaimer">
   <p>
    Here i want to print content 3rd time
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what exactly i was looking for, Thanks a lot for this easiest way of extracting last element and inserting there after in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

using `.append()`, it need to select the parent element or `<div id="page">`

```
newRecord = '''
<div class="record">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title">
      Something here to display 3rd time
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="disclaimer">
    <p>Here i want to print content 3rd time</p>
  </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(sourceHTML, 'html.parser')
page = soup.select_one('#page')
page.append(BeautifulSoup(newRecord, 'html.parser'))
print(soup.prettify())
```